# Accessing Model.Properties in MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I am trying to understand why when ever i want to access a properties in my Model like this

```
@Model.Username
```

It gives me this error:

```
Compilation Error
Description: An error occurred during the compilation of a resource required to service this request. Please review the following specific error details and modify your source code appropriately.

Compiler Error Message: CS1061: 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<IntegrateApp.Models.EditUserViewModel>' does not contain a definition for 'Username' and no extension method 'Username' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<IntegrateApp.Models.EditUserViewModel>' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
```

However, it works if i do it this way:

```
@foreach (var item in Model) {
    <tr>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.UserName)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.FirstName)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.MiddleName)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Surname)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Email)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new { id = item.UserName }) |
            @Html.ActionLink("Details", "Details", new { id = item.UserName }) |
            @Html.ActionLink("Delete", "Delete", new { id = item.UserName })
        </td>
    </tr>
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first code snippet is referring to the `Model` property of the view and that property is type `IEnumerable<EditUserViewModel>`.  Does the `IEnumerable<T>` class have a `Username` property?  No, it doesn't, hence the error.

The second code snippet uses a `foreach` loop to enumerate that `IEnumerable<EditUserViewModel>` so, inside the loop, `item` is a single `EditUserViewModel` object and the `EditUserViewModel` class does have a `Username` property.

It comes down to the fact that the model is a list and the list doesn't have that property; it's the items in the list that have that property.

Comment: Thanks i just realize it. Turns out that if i still want to access it should use FirstOrDefault method (then specify which property i want). I'll accept your answer once i am allowed.

Comment: If you only have one item then you you should not be declaring your model as being a list of items in the first place.  If your view is for displaying multiple `EditUserViewModel` objects then declare the model as type `IEnumerable<EditUserViewModel>` but if it's just for displaying one `EditUserViewModel` object then declare the model as type `EditUserViewModel`.  Don't specify the model as being an egg carton if your view is for displaying an egg.